# IE JS Type Error: Object does not support this property or method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to write a cookie to track visitor recency and I'm hitting a wall with IE8. The error my logs are showing for IE users is the not-so-informative: **TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method.**

Any idea what I need to revise in the code below so it works with IE?

```
var currentDate = Date.now();
var cookies = document.cookie.match(/jcom\=.+\}/);

if (cookies == null) {
var cookieBase = '{"created":"createdNull","lastVisit":"visitNull"}';
var siteTime = $.parseJSON(cookieBase);
siteTime.created = currentDate;
siteTime.lastVisit = currentDate;
cookieOut = "{\"created\":" + siteTime.created + ",\"lastVisit\":" + siteTime.lastVisit + "};expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2020 20:47:11 UTC;path=/";
document.cookie="jcom=" + cookieOut;
}
else {
var cookies = document.cookie.match(/jcom\=.+\}/)[0];
var cookieSplit1 = cookies.split('=')[1];
var cookieSplit= cookieSplit1.split(';')[0]
var siteTime = $.parseJSON(cookieSplit);
siteTime.lastVisit = currentDate;
cookieOut = "{\"created\":" + siteTime.created + ",\"lastVisit\":"+ siteTime.lastVisit + "};expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2020 20:47:11 UTC;path=/";
document.cookie="jcom=" + cookieOut;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: I wish I knew. I'm discovering the error from our logs, not in a debugger...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 does not support `Date.now()`. You can implement it yourself very easily:

```
if( !Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() {return new Date.getTime();};
}
```

Comment: If I had any rep I'd vote this way up (and sorry I don't; will come back to this thread when I do). Looks like this did the trick!

Comment: You can still Accept the answer by clicking the check mark - glad I could help!